# How add new element to json variable?

Tags: python, json

I have this kind of json variable:
var = {"header":['x', 'y', 'z']}
How can I add new element to header in Python?

Comment: Show your attempt please

Comment: For example like that var["header"]['4'] = "abc" or like that iter(var).next()["header"] = "abc" .But not work

Comment: That's not JSON; it's a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `append()`:

```py
var['header'].append('abc')
```

Comment: I believe you meant to write `append` in your code snippet

Comment: This solution I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: @Cubix48. I have corrected that now.